# Ubuntu 20.10 - Steelseries Arctis 9 Bluetooth settings output and input

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone

Every time I try to use the headset mic the output settings change to mono, and if I change back to stereo the mic setting change automatically to the laptop built-in mic

[stereo mode w/ laptop built-in mic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP5La.png)

[mono mode w/ headset mic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DZiE.png)

If anything needs clarification, feel free to ask. Hope I can get this fixed.

can anyone help me please?

(sorry for the bad English)

Comment: Correct if the the headphones are set to stereo the profile does not allow mic and stereo at same time mono does.

Answer (score 1):

Correct if the the headphones are set to stereo the profile does not allow mic and stereo at same time mono does.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for others coming here from google: If you use a jack cable, you can have stereo on your headphone with bluetooth only for the headset microphone. In my case good enough, because I don't have to move more than 2 meters from my laptop.

Comment: Not a solution the OP has already said he has a built in mic.

Comment: @David The built in mic will pick up all surround sounds. That's a big advantage of using a headset instead. I specifically explained how you could have stereo on your headphone and still use the headset microphone on Ubuntu.

Comment: helpful to me, looking up linux support for this headset considering buying, thanks. how is mic quality?

Comment: Mic quality is actually not that great. It's good enough for video calls, but no where near as good as when using the dongle that I got with the head set.